# Is There a Way to Tell If Someone Has Set An Alert For A File?

Tags: alert

I'd like to track which users have set an alert.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Go to `Site Settings` -> `Site Administration` -> `User alerts`.  This will show you who has alerts set up on the current site.  You can update (1 user at a time) to see what the alerts are set on.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got access to a Powershell terminal, I found this script that may provide what you need: 
https://gist.github.com/nlarkin/5067267

This script will crawl through all Site Collections within your farm and give you an Excel report with all set alerts.